# How to create a role that contains the members of a crew assigned to the current workorder

Tags: maximo

I have a communication template that currently sends an email to a single person.  I would like to have the template send to a Role whose members are the members of the crew assigned to the workorder.  I am not sure the best way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a relationship from workorder to person, or find a relationship or chain of relationships, that will find all the people in the crew, then use that relationship to create a role based on a data set related to the current record.